# jQuery-Why is my .on('click') event handler not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.laravel-like').on('click','i',function(){
  if($(this).hasClass('disabled'))
   return false;
   alert($("#like").attr("data-item-id"));
alert($("#like").attr('data-vote'));
)}
```

When I click on the `i` tag in the `laravel-like` dive on the page it doesn't work at all.It doesn't even log  any error in he console.

But when I change the `'laravel-like'` to `document` it works but only when I click on any where on the page.I want it to work only when I click on a `i` element inside the `laravel-like` div

This my html:

```
<div class="laravel-like">
    <i id="like"
       class="icon   laravelLike-icon thumbs up"
       data-item-id="9"
       data-vote="1">
    </i>
    <span id="9-total-like">1</span>
    <i id="dislike"
       class="icon  outline laravelLike-icon thumbs down"
       data-item-id="9"
       data-vote="-1">
   </i>
   <span id="9-total-dislike">0</span>
</div>
```

Pls help.

Comment: im guessing your icon is using `::before`

Comment: can u add code spinet. so we easily debug

Comment: Why you need 'i' parameter for on click function. You can use `$('.laravel-like').on('click',function(){`

Comment: @Alvin Your snippet is not an exact equivalent. The OP is using _delegated_ event handling which may or may not mean that the content is dynamically loaded...

Comment: @War10ck ....pls explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your displayed JavaScript has two syntax errors.

1. `)}` should be `})`
2. You are missing another `})` at the end of the code

Next, your click handler is set to run only on `i` elements that are inside of `.laravel-like` elements. If your `i` elements don't have any visible content to click on, then the `click` event can't fire. Here, I've simply supplied `X` as the content for the two `i` elements and if you click either of them, it works.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.laravel-like').on('click','i',function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('disabled'))
     return false;
    alert($("#like").attr("data-item-id"));
    alert($("#like").attr('data-vote'));
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="laravel-like">
    <i id="like"
       class="icon laravelLike-icon thumbs up"
       data-item-id="9"
       data-vote="1">x
    </i>
    <span id="9-total-like">1</span>
    <i id="dislike"
       class="icon outline laravelLike-icon thumbs down"
       data-item-id="9"
       data-vote="-1">x
   </i>
   <span id="9-total-dislike">0</span>
</div>
```